# Python C Extensions Optimize For Speed (Linux)

Tags: python, c, linux, windows, optimization

I am trying to compile some Python C extensions for both Windows and Linux. The most time consuming part of my program seems to be a `for` loop with a significant amount of simple calculations. When running it on Linux, it is about 2x slower than on Windows. Adding `-O2` or `-O3` seems to help a little bit, but not much. Are there any other optimization methods that would get it to a comparable speed?

The compiler I'm using is GCC: gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

Here is the python equivalent. The C code is using a loop instead of numpy operations:

```
def cf(sigma, kappa, theta, rho, s0, v0, r, ttm, n,
              alpha = 1.0, delta = 0.01, lambda_ = 0.002, u = -0.5):
        x = np.log(s0)
        phi = np.arange(n) * delta - 1j*(alpha + 1)
        qq = kappa - 1j * rho * sigma * phi
        d = np.sqrt(qq ** 2 + sigma ** 2 * phi ** 2 + 1j * sigma ** 2 * phi)
        c = (qq - d) / (qq + d)

        cc = 1j * phi * r * ttm + ((kappa * theta) / sigma ** 2) * \
            ((qq - d) * ttm - 2 * np.log((-c * np.exp(-d * ttm) + 1) / (1 - c)))
        dd = ((qq - d) / sigma ** 2) * (1 - np.exp(-d * ttm)) / (-c * np.exp(-d * ttm)+1)
        f = np.exp(cc + dd * v0 + 1j * phi * x)
        return f
```

Comment: If the code is working (a hard requirement) and you can create a [mcve] to show, then this is probable better asked on [the code review SE site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What compiler are you running on Windows?  Add the command line options you're using for compilation on both architectures.  There could be features enabled on one that aren't enabled on the other.  Could be a security feature or something as simple as packing or alignment differences, or it could come down to different levels of optimizations.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's kind of hard to post any code that would be useful because the calculations are using complex numbers that make it very difficult to read. I can post the Python equivalent if that would help

Comment: @jwdonahue It looks like the windows compiler flags being added are: `/c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT`. It is using Visual Studio 2019 C++ build tools

Comment: [Edit] your post to include the relevant information for how you are compiling each target. There are many reasons why a program compiled by different compilers, targeting different OS's will have different performance profiles. Even after careful "balancing" of compiler switches, there's OS configuration, different loads on the processors, memory, drives, etc, even if the machines are identical. You may need to adjust your kernel config to favor compute intensive threads for instance. I seem to recall Windows kernel recognizes such threads and gives them temporary boosts now and then.

Comment: There are a few numeric libraries for C that can perform many of the operations of numpy. You might want to search for such a library.